# In ASP.NET how do I access a configuration from the client side?

Tags: asp.net, kubernetes, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have both a server and client in the same project, they have been deployed in a dockerfile to k8s with the entry point being the server.

However when I try to add scopes for Azure Authentication in the client, it cannot find the variables that I deployed the app with on k8s.

```
builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAD)
```

The server is fine, but the client is not. In both the server and client I have a Program.cs file.

Are there any suggestions or things I could be doing wrong?

Comment: How (where) did you "add scopes for Azure Authentication" ? You have 2 appsettings too.

Comment: @HH The scopes are added in the client in Program.cs. I don't want to use appsettings as I would prefer to deploy my settings with k8s.

Comment: does your appsettings.json file contains the "AzureAD" element ?

Also as I can see on your posted code, you are missing a quote:

````builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAD)````